# How to run C project written in linux on Windows?

Tags: linux, netbeans, mingw

I need to run C project written in Linux on Windows. The project contains the following: main.c, makefile, (.c) and (.h) files under folder (libs), and it includes "GL/glut.h" (openGL).
I have tried run it under Visual Studio, but didn't work out. Now, I am working with NetBeans under MinGW compiler. I did all steps mentioned to make NetBeans use MinGW compiler, but still the makefile doesn't compile, and I can't understand the error behind.
Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Find below the makefile:

```
EXECUTABLE = main
CC = g++
CWD=$(shell pwd)
INCLUDES = 
CFLAGS= -O3 -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer #-static -Wall
LIBFLAGS = -L./ -lGL -lGLU -lglut #-L/usr/X11R6/lib # -lXxf86vm
SOURCE_FILES = $(shell find -name \*.c)
INTERM_DIR=obj
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
clean:  
     $(RM) -rf $(INTERM_DIR) $(EXECUTABLE)
.PHONY: clean
$(INTERM_DIR) :
      mkdir -p $@
$(INTERM_DIR)/%.dep: %.c
     mkdir -p `dirname $@`
     echo -n `dirname $@`/ > $@
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS_COMMON) $< -MM | sed -r -e 's,^(.*)\.o\s*\:,\1.o $@ :,g' >> $@
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
  -include $(SOURCE_FILES:./%.c=./$(INTERM_DIR)/%.dep)
endif
$(INTERM_DIR)/%.o: ./%.c
      mkdir -p `dirname $@`
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
$(EXECUTABLE): $(SOURCE_FILES:./%.c=./$(INTERM_DIR)/%.o)
      mkdir -p `dirname $@`
      $(CC) $^ $(LIBFLAGS) -o $@
```

The error I got:
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c 'C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe' -MM
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

COMPILE FILE FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 306ms)

Comment: When you post something related to an error, cut&paste the error IS mandatory. You should add all the proofs. Let's expand your posts with more details in the future. Ps: let's look to cygwin in order to compile a linux program 1:1 in windows.

Comment: It might be worth setting up a CMake file to enable cross platform makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you install Visual Studio it gives the option to run with Linux. Another way you might be able to get around this is to use a VM with a Linux OS.